# How to prevent scrolling while 'ctrl' is pressed in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Using PyQt5 I am viewing an image in a QGraphicsView. I want to be able to zoom in/out while pressing ctrl and using the mouse wheel. I have this working, however if the image is too large, and there are scroll bars, it ignores the zoom functionality until you scroll to the top or bottom.

How can I fix this to where it does not scroll when ctrl is pressed, while allowing it to zoom in/out.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QLineEdit, QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsScene
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, Qt
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from PIL import ImageQt
import sys

class step1(QWidget):
    changeViewSignal = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(step1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.name = QLineEdit(self)
        self.fileBtn = QPushButton("Select file", self)
        self.nextBtn = QPushButton("Next", self)
        self.graphicsView = QGraphicsView()
        # self.graphicsView.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        # self.graphicsView.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow)
        self.graphicsView.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.name)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.fileBtn)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.nextBtn)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)

        self.fileBtn.clicked.connect(self.convert_file)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        modifiers = QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
        if modifiers == Qt.ControlModifier:
            self.graphicsView.scrollContentsBy(0,0)
            x = event.angleDelta().y() / 120
            if x > 0:
                self.graphicsView.scale(1.05, 1.05)
            elif x < 0:
                self.graphicsView.scale(.95, .95)

    def convert_file(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', 'c:\\', "PDF Files (*.pdf)")
        if len(fname[0]) > 0:
            pages = convert_from_path(fname[0])
            images = []
            qimage = ImageQt.toqpixmap(pages[0])
            item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(qimage)
            scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
            scene.addItem(item)
            self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)
        

       

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = step1()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrolling is first handled by the QGraphicsView before it would be propagated up to the parent widget where you are reimplementing the `wheelEvent`. This is why the scrolling occurs according to the normal QGraphicsView behavior when it has space to scroll.

A solution is to subclass QGraphicsView and reimplement the `wheelEvent` there instead.

```
class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier:
            x = event.angleDelta().y() / 120
            if x > 0:
                self.scale(1.05, 1.05)
            elif x < 0:
                self.scale(.95, .95)
        else:
            super().wheelEvent(event)
```

Then use the subclass name here:

```
self.graphicsView = GraphicsView()
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the proper solution proposed by [alec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69060238/2001654), there's also the option of using an event filter, which can be useful for UIs created in Designer without the need of using promoted widgets.

The important aspect to keep in mind is that the event filter **must** be installed on the view's [`viewport()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport) (the widget in which the contents of the scene are actually rendered and, possibly, scrolled), because *that* is the widget that will receive the wheel event: input events are always sent to the widget *under* the mouse (or has keyboard focus)<sup>[1]</sup>, and possibly propagated to their parents if the event is not handled<sup>[2]</sup>.

```
class step1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...
        self.graphicsView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == event.Wheel and event.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier:
            x = event.angleDelta().y() / 120
            if x > 0:
                self.graphicsView.scale(1.05, 1.05)
            elif x < 0:
                self.graphicsView.scale(.95, .95)
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Returning `True` means that the *viewport* has handled the event, and it should *not* be propagated to the parent; QGraphicsView is based on QAbstractScrollArea, and if a wheel event is not handled by the viewport it will call the base `wheelEvent` implementation of the viewport's parent (the graphics view), which by default will *post* the event to the scroll bars. If the filter returns `True`, it will avoid that propagation, thus preventing scrolling.

Note that you should not use `scrollContentsBy` unless you ***really*** know what you're doing; as the documentation [explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#scrollContentsBy): «Calling this function in order to scroll programmatically is an error, use the scroll bars instead».

<sup>[1] Mouse events are always sent to the *topmost* widget under the mouse, unless a *modal* child window is active, or there is a *mouse grabber*, which is a widget that has received a mouse button press event but didn't receive a mouse button release event yet, or a widget on which [`grabMouse()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabMouse) was explicitly called. Keyboard events are always sent to the widget *of the **active window*** that has current focus, or the widget on which [`grabKeyboard()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabKeyboard) has been explicitly called.</sup>
<sup>[2] "handled event" can be a confusing concept: it doesn't mean that the widget actually "does" something with the event, nor that it doesn't, no matter if the event then becomes *accepted* or *ignored*. A widget could "ignore" an event and still react to it in some way: for instance, you might need to notify the user that the event has been *received*, but let the parent manage it anyway.</sup>